# Laravel web.php is not redirecting properly.

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

Below is my web.php content

```
Route::get('/myRoutes', function () {return view('myRoutes.routeIndex');})->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/myRoutes/{route}', 'routes@show')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/myRoutes/create', 'routes@create');
```

Below is my resource controller(route.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\route;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class routes extends Controller
{  
public function create()
    {
        return view('myRoutes.routeCreate');
    }
    public function show(route $route)
    {
        return view('myRoutes.routeShow', compact('route'));
    }
?>
```

Now if i visit mydomain.com/myRoutes, it gives me a list of routes available.(working as expected)

If I visit mydomain.com/myRoutes/1, it gives me the record with id=1(working as expected)

Now the issue is if I visit mydomain.com/myRoutes/create, it returns a 404 error that the page not found. If I comment out the following line in web.php

```
Route::get('/myRoutes/{route}', 'routes@show')->middleware('auth');
```

then mydomain.com/myRoutes/create works as expected. I think laravel is confused between /myRoutes/{id} and /myRoutes/create. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

in your `web.php` ,add create route before your show route.

```
Route::get('/myRoutes', function () {return view('myRoutes.routeIndex');})->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/myRoutes/create', 'routes@create');
Route::get('/myRoutes/{route}', 'routes@show')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: always put routes with parameters `/myRoutes/{route}` at last .  any fixed route like `/myRoutes/route1` , `/myRoutes/route2`  ....will not found ,and redirect to 404...if you added it before  ,  basically it is override your fixed route ...and execute your parameterised route

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `create` route before your `show` route in `web.php`